# How much more do I have to learn?

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding

So I started learning java sometime ago and now I am understanding packages.

My main goal is to do minecraft modding. Can someone with modding experience please tell me how hard(or easy) minecraft modding is? And how much time will it take for me to get to a level when I can start modding?

Comment: It mostly depends on what you mod you are planning on doing. If you are going for a simple mod, with a few items blocks and maybe some entities then you only need to know the basics of Java, like for loops, if statements, etc. Also you will need to know everything about classes and inheritance. But if you are going for a more advanced mod(like those made by iChun), then you will need to learn much more about Java, and you should have at least intermediate skills and some experience, I recommend starting of by making a simple mod, while learning Java, and then moving on to more advanced mods.

Comment: oh, i know the basics and know OOP but am not that familiar with inheritance yet

Comment: Yeah inheritance is important. There are some great tutorials on thenewboston's channel.